# Stub curren_user for login_required rspec 3.1 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I cannot seem to stub my @current_user so that my before_filter :login_required passes and I get the correct template instead of redirected to the login screen.

here is my controller spec:

```
 before(:each) do
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return FactoryGirl.build(:signed_up_user)
  end

  it "index action should render index template" do
    get :index
    expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
```

I believe this is the newer rspec syntax for stubbing.

There are some examples using the controller.stub method, but this doesn't seem to work.  I just want to stub @current_user variable so it will look like a user is logged in so I can get back to testing my controller with an actual controller spec.  Right now, I'm only using feature specs.

I've been working on this for weeks!

EDIT:

I'm not using devise.  I created my own authentication following Ryan Bates nifty:authentication.

```
before_filter :login_required


def login_required
  unless current_user
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

I'm just trying to set the @current_user variable (I guess I could also set the session[:user_id], but haven't been able to get this to work either) for my controller tests.  This should allow the before_filter to pass and allow me to test my controller methods.  I'm testing the authentication in a feature spec.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using devise, on the [wiki about rspec testing](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29#controller-specs) they explain how to add devise rspec helpers,

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

When you do so you can then log in using any user created in the database

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:signed_up_user) }
before :each do
  sign_in user
end
```

And that's it, you now have a logged in session.

Comment: I am not using devise.  I wanted to build my own authentication from scratch.  Similar to nifty:authentication by Ryan Bates.